# Changing string options in a combobox

Tags: user-interface, go, combobox, andlabs-ui

I am using [`andlabs/ui`](https://godoc.org/github.com/andlabs/ui) to create a simple GUI which has [`Combobox`](https://godoc.org/github.com/andlabs/ui#Combobox).

It seems that it is not possible to remove or change strings options once they have been added to Combobox (through its `Append` function).

The only functions available seem to be `Append`, `OnSelected`, `Selected` and `SetSelected`.

Can I change string options already added to combobox in andlabs/ui? Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to the readme on github: `Package ui is currently mid-alpha software. Much of what is currently present runs stabily enough for the examples and perhaps some small programs to work, but the stability is still a work-in-progress, much of what is already there is not feature-complete, some of it will be buggy on certain platforms, and there's a lot of stuff missing. The libui README has more information.` Thus I think your best shot would be to raise an issue with your question here https://github.com/andlabs/ui/issues

Comment: However, it seems to work well with small applications and I think, because of its small size and simple syntax, it has good potential. Another similar and good one is `Fyne`: https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne